# How can I access postgresql without knowing any internal database information?

Tags: database, postgresql, go, backend

I was given an application that can be deployed by using `docker-compose` to work on. `docker-compose` eventually runs a number of containers, one which houses a `postgresql` database, which is currently PostgreSQL 14.

When I get a shell inside of the database container, I seem to be completely locked out of the database and I have no idea how to get in and see what is going on. I have root in the container running the database, and when I do a `ls -l /proc/*/exe` I see this:

```
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 postgres postgres 0 Sep 15 04:18 /proc/1/exe -> /usr/lib/postgresql/14/bin/postgres
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 postgres postgres 0 Sep 15 04:27 /proc/23/exe -> /usr/lib/postgresql/14/bin/postgres
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 postgres postgres 0 Sep 15 04:27 /proc/24/exe -> /usr/lib/postgresql/14/bin/postgres
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 postgres postgres 0 Sep 15 04:27 /proc/25/exe -> /usr/lib/postgresql/14/bin/postgres
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 postgres postgres 0 Sep 15 04:27 /proc/26/exe -> /usr/lib/postgresql/14/bin/postgres
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 postgres postgres 0 Sep 15 04:27 /proc/27/exe -> /usr/lib/postgresql/14/bin/postgres
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 postgres postgres 0 Sep 15 04:27 /proc/28/exe -> /usr/lib/postgresql/14/bin/postgres
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 postgres postgres 0 Sep 15 04:27 /proc/42/exe -> /usr/lib/postgresql/14/bin/postgres
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 postgres postgres 0 Sep 15 04:27 /proc/44/exe -> /usr/lib/postgresql/14/bin/postgres
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root     root     0 Sep 15 04:27 /proc/46/exe
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root     root     0 Sep 15 04:19 /proc/53/exe
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 postgres postgres 0 Sep 15 04:27 /proc/54/exe -> /usr/bin/bash
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 postgres postgres 0 Sep 15 16:49 /proc/self/exe -> /usr/bin/ls
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 postgres postgres 0 Sep 15 16:49 /proc/thread-self/exe -> /usr/bin/ls
```

So clearly, postgres is in fact running. However, when I try to run `psql`, it tells me there is no such role or database as `root`, so I `su postgres`, which is the default account, and it tells me the same errors, no such role, no such database as `postgres`. However, since I cannot access the server via `psql`, I have no idea how to proceed and find out which roles there are for me to try to login and examine things, I can't even get into `psql`. Even if I use just the `-U` flag without a database listed, it still gives me the `no such role` error.

I looked at the config file and it does have the standard default port, it's on 127.0.0.1, and it's using the default `trust` auth. Please note the I've checked the source code for the application I am working on, and found some database creds, and I have tried the usernames that the application supposedly uses, and the same result occurs.

How can I figure out what the actual roles are when I am unable to connect to the database server via `psql`? is there some alternate way for me to get this information? The application is written in `Go`.

Comment: The app must be using a so-called "connection string" when calling `database/sql.Open`, it should contain all the relevant data except for may be some defaults which are then contained in the PG's config file and/or environment variables and/or command-line parameters passed to it. The former can be obtained via `cat /proc/$pid/environ | xargs -0 -n 1` and the latter–via `cat /proc/$pid/cmdline | xargs -0 -n 1`